# Data Entry form with vba codes

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have an excel form in one sheet as data entry (1- Textbox1 = Name, 2-Textbox2 = Old, 3-Textbox3= Email )

Comment: What do you want meaning by "an excel form in one sheet"? What kind of controls are the three text boxes? Which is their real name? "TextBox1" or "Name" for the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything to clarify my question... When come here and need help, it is good to clarify any question and if you do not understand what is it about to **ask for clarifications**.

Anyhow, I am trying helping you suggesting the next scenario:

1. I assumes that you name "an excel form in one sheet" the sheet itself, having three text boxes (ActiveX type) and a combo box (also ActiveX type).

The three text boxes will have the name "TextBox1", "TextBox2" and "TextBox3". If not so, the code which will follow would be easy to adapt at your real names.

The combo box name should be "ComboOptions". After creation, when in Design mode, right click on it, choose `Properties` and set A1:A2 at its `ListFillRange` property. Then add "Teachers" in "A1" and "Students" in "A2.

2. Paste the next code in a standard module:

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, workSh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
 Dim cbOption As MSForms.ComboBox, txtName As MSForms.TextBox, txtOld As MSForms.TextBox, txtEmail As MSForms.TextBox

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set sh2 = sh.Next 'Worksheets("Teachers")
 Set sh3 = sh2.Next 'Worksheets("Students")

 Set cbOption = sh.OLEObjects("ComboOptions").Object

 If cbOption.Value = "" Then MsgBox "No option chosen in combo box...": Exit Sub
 If cbOption.Value = "Teachers" Then
    Set workSh = sh2
 ElseIf cbOption.Value = "Students" Then
    Set workSh = sh3
 End If
 Set txtName = sh.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
 Set txtOld = sh.OLEObjects("TextBox2").Object
 Set txtEmail = sh.OLEObjects("TextBox3").Object
 If txtName.Text = "" Or txtOld.Text = "" Or txtEmail.Text = "" Then _
       MsgBox "All involved text boxes must have a value!": Exit Sub
 lastRow = workSh.Range("B" & workSh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    With workSh
       .Range("B" & lastRow).Value = txtName.Value
       .Range("C" & lastRow).Value = txtOld.Value
       .Range("D" & lastRow).Value = txtEmail.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

3. Select one option in the combo box, run the above code and send some feedback about the behavior against your expectations.

Comment: @Mohsen: Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: @Mohsen: **Yes, you may**. But the idea in our community is to help you learn... And this is better done if you try it by yourself. Please, send the workbook to me, but in the meantime try what you understand from my above recommendations. You may have the surprise to make it working by your own, which should be much more useful...

Comment: @Mohsen: Did you send it? I did not receive anything...

Comment: @Mohsen: Asking about sending, I thought that you could see the private mail in my profile. But you can share it on a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free site, easy to be used. You will only post here the generated link,,,

Comment: @Mohsen: OK. I will download it and configure in some minutes...

Comment: @Mohsen: I am looking to the workbook you sent and nothing match what you said in your question... I can understand that it was a dummy approach, but you should also send a dummy file containing what you said "Students" and "Teachers". How to configure the controls I was talking about, if I cannot know what you try moving on the sheet you mentioned now?

Comment: @Mohsen: OK. I configured it to send data in the two enumerated sheets, but the moved data does not match the header of the new sheets, as you were talking about dummy data. Of course, seeing the way it works, it should be easy to adapt the solution according to your needs. Please, download the file from [here](https://easyupload.io/30h4i5), test it and send some feedback. All controls are in the sheet right side. You must press "Actualization" button... I think that after actualization, the three text boxes should be clear, but this is something operational and I hope you can handle it...

Comment: @Mohsen: I can do it only if I understand what you mean... I do not understand what "reverse the code on a Module3" does mean. Do you need the code in discussion to be moved 'Module3'? I cannot believe that...

Comment: @Mohsen: With other words, you want the procedure to be moved from the actual module to the Module3. Is this understanding correct? If Yes, you can go in the respective module, select the procedure, press `Ctrl + x`, go into Module3, click on the place you want to move it and press `Ctrl + V`. If this is not what you want, please try clarifying...

Comment: @Mohsen:  But, beside that, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...